# Meshgrid for too large dataset

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset, consisting of three arrays `b0`, `b1`, `b2` with two columns each. I want to draw a plot that shows for each point x, y in the plane the number

```
H =   #entries (x1, y1) in b0 with x1 < x and y1 < y
    – #entries (x1, y1) in b1 with x1 < x and y1 < y
    + #entries (x1, y1) in b2 with x1 < x and y1 < y
```

At the moment, I do

```
x, y = np.sort(np.vstack((b0, b1, b2)), axis=0).T
N = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y))
H = np.count_nonzero(np.all(N[None,:,:] >= b0[:,:,None,None], axis=1), axis=0)\
  - np.count_nonzero(np.all(N[None,:,:] >= b1[:,:,None,None], axis=1), axis=0)\
  + np.count_nonzero(np.all(N[None,:,:] >= b2[:,:,None,None], axis=1), axis=0)
```

and plot this using matplotlib's `pcolormesh()`. Each of `b0`, `b1`, `b2` may contain around 1000 entries. The above approach is unusably slow. What can I change?

Comment: Can you provide example code which creates b0, b1, and b2 with the appropriate shapes and random data? I'm finding it hard to visualize what this is doing.